# pgfplots 'typeset ticklabel' gets stuck with siunitx \num

Tags: pgfplots, siunitx, incompatibility

I want to format my axis labels with `\num`, but if I use `typeset ticklabel` with `\num` inside the compilation gets stuck.  See this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\def\mynum#1{(#1)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    typeset ticklabel/.code = { \mynum{#1} },
    % typeset ticklabel/.code = { \num{#1} },
  ]
  \addplot [red] plot [domain=-1:1] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With `\mynum`  to do some arbitrary formatting it works, but with `siunitx`'s `\num` it gets stuck.  What's wrong here?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your code, but I don't see this `typeset ticklabel` key documented in the `pgfplots` manual either (Revision 1.17 from 2020/02/29). One thing you can use here is `xticklabel = {$\num{\tick}$}, yticklabel = {$\num{\tick}$}`. This works. You can verify it for instance with `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}, zero-decimal-to-integer}` after your `\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}` line.

Comment: `typeset ticklabel/.code` is only for internal use. It gets "forwarded" in `pgfplots.code.tex` via `\def\pgfplots@ticklabel@typeset@arg#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/typeset ticklabel/.@cmd}{#1}\pgfeov}`, so you cannot use arbitrary macros there. One way to go is as outlined in the above comment, or you can play with the number format options offered via pgf.

Comment: @frougon Oh, yeah, that does it!  I found `typeset ticklabel` browsing the code (I was looking how `typeset ticklabels with strut` is implemented), but it seems that's not the way to go.  Care to write an answer with that, please?

Comment: @Lazysquirrel I guess I was lazy too, looking at the code instead of the documentation ;-)  Thanks, but I'd rather stick to `siunitx` here

Comment: @LaTeXer Sure, writing an answer.

Comment: @LaTeXer, just for curiosity: **Why** do you want to print the `ticklabels` with the `\num` command?

Comment: @StefanPinnow Mainly because I already know how to use `\num` to format the number exactly how I want (for example, groups of three decimal digits, as my actual plot has 6 decimal places in some cases), so I thought it would be easier than to write everything with PGF.  That said, I would appreciate an answer with an alternative! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typeset ticklabel` key isn't documented in the `pgfplots` manual (Revision 1.17 from 2020/02/29). According to [Lazy squirrel's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/230294/lazy-squirrel), it is only for internal use. So, you can't really expect anything from it without expert knowledge of some `pgfplots` internals.

One way that is documented and works is to use the `xticklabel` and `yticklabel` styles (see section *Tick Coordinates and Label Texts* in the manual). For instance, in the following example, we ask `siunitx` to use the comma as decimal separator in tick labels and to omit trailing zeros in the decimal part:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}, zero-decimal-to-integer}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xticklabel = {$\num{\tick}$},
    yticklabel = {$\num{\tick}$},
  ]
  \addplot [red] plot [domain=-1:1] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the `siunitx` setup could be done locally, as in:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}, zero-decimal-to-integer}
\begin{axis}[
    xticklabel = {$\num{\tick}$},
    yticklabel = {$\num{\tick}$},
  ]
  \addplot [red] plot [domain=-1:1] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

(in which case it wouldn't affect anything outside the `tikzpicture`), or even in the optional argument of `\num`:

```latex
xticklabel = {%
  $\num[output-decimal-marker={,},
        zero-decimal-to-integer]{\tick}$%
}
```

Comment: Riwelcome :-) and upvoted your answer.

Comment: Always glad to see you, Sebastiano. :-)

Comment: The same also for me :-) :-)